# How to add percentage by each category in Python pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, percentage, subtotal

I am working on a survey and the data looks like this:

```
ID    Q1    Q2    Q3    Gender    Age    Dep    Ethnicity
001   Y      N    Y      F         22     IT        W
002   N      Y    Y      M         35     HR        W
003   Y      N    N      F         20     IT        A
004   Y      N    Y      M         54     OPRE      B
005   Y      N    Y      M         42     OPRE      B
```

Now, I'd like to add two indexes Dep and Gender to create a table like:

```
Question   Dep   Response  ID    % response
     Q1     IT    Y        2     100
            IT    N        0     0
            HR    Y        0     0    
            HR    N        1     100  
            OPRE  Y        2     100 
            OPRE  N        0     0  
     Q2     IT    Y        0     0    
            IT    N        2     100
            HR    Y        1     100 
            HR    N        0     0 
            OPRE  Y        0     0
            OPRE  N        2     100 
     Q3 ......
```

My codes are like this:

```
df['% response'] = df['ID']/df['ID'].sum()
```

Which gives me

```
Question   Dep   Response  ID    % response
     Q1     IT    Y        2     20
            IT    N        0     0
            HR    Y        0     0    
            HR    N        1     10  
            OPRE  Y        2     20
            OPRE  N        0     0  
     Q2     IT    Y        0     0    
            IT    N        2     20
            HR    Y        1     10
            HR    N        0     0 
            OPRE  Y        0     0
            OPRE  N        2     20
     Q3 ......
```

I think the denominator is wrong. It should be grouped by the question and Dep and then do the count instead of sum all the IDs.
Does anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your initial dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "Q1": ["Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
        "Q2": ["N", "Y", "N", "N", "N"],
        "Q3": ["Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y"],
        "Gender": ["F", "M", "F", "M", "M"],
        "Age": [22, 35, 20, 54, 42],
        "Dep": ["IT", "HR", "IT", "OPRE", "OPRE"],
        "Ethnicity": ["W", "W", "A", "B", "B"],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Reshape the dataframe
df = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            df[[col, "Dep", "ID"]]
            .rename(columns={col: "Response"})
            .assign(Question=col)
            for col in ("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")
        ]
    )
    .groupby(["Question", "Dep", "Response"])
    .count()
)

# Add 'zero' Y/N rows
for question in ("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"):
    for dep in ("HR", "IT", "OPRE"):
        for response in ("Y", "N"):
            df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({(question, dep, response): {"ID": 0}}).T])

# Remove duplicated rows and reindex
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep="first")].sort_index(ascending=[True, True, False])

# Add percentage column
for question in ("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"):
    for dep in ("HR", "IT", "OPRE"):
        for response in ("Y", "N"):
            try:
                df.loc[(question, dep, response), "% response"] = (
                    100
                    * df.loc[(question, dep, response), "ID"]
                    / df.loc[(question, dep)].sum().values[0]
                )
            except KeyError:
                pass

# Cleanup
df = df.astype(int)
```

So that:

```py
print(df)
# Output
                        ID  % response
Question Dep  Response
Q1       HR   Y          0           0
              N          1         100
         IT   Y          2         100
              N          0           0
         OPRE Y          2         100
              N          0           0
Q2       HR   Y          1         100
              N          0           0
         IT   Y          0           0
              N          2         100
         OPRE Y          0           0
              N          2         100
Q3       HR   Y          1         100
              N          0           0
         IT   Y          1          50
              N          1          50
         OPRE Y          2         100
              N          0           0
```